# How can I send client side events in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to send an event to google analytics that occurs on the client side in an application made in Next.js, I tried to do it as below, but I can't access the `const handleUserClick` in `useEffect`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUserClick = () => {
      sendEvent(eventTag)
    };
  }, []);

return ( ...
  <a rel="noopener noreferrer" onClick={() => handleUserClick()}>
```

What is the best way to send events on SSR sites? If this is the best way, how can I access `handleUserClick`?

Comment: There is no need to put `handleUserClick` inside the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal but my event should only be sent after the click. How do I do that?

Comment: Declaring a function doesn't call it. You have to invoke a function, i.e. `handleUserClick()`, for it to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to put `handleUserClick` inside the `useEffect` hook. You can simply do something like this:

```
const handleUserClick = () => {
  sendEvent(eventTag)
};

return ( ...
  <a rel="noopener noreferrer" onClick={handleUserClick}>
```